# How to target a specific div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sorry that I bother in this manner... I think I have a really simple problem, but I can't get a fix for it...

(I'm using vanilla Javascript)

I have multiple image carousels in a page, and I cannot make them work.

I managed to make one carousel to work, but if I insert a second one, it doesn't work.

I tried to give id for each div that represents a carousel `id="voucher1"` and target them in javascript with

```
carouselA = carousel('#voucher1')
function carousel(id){
   const carouselSlide = document.querySelector(id + '.carousel-slide');
}
```

but it doesn't work...

This is my HTML

```
        <div class="vouchers">
            <span class="voucherstitle">Gutscheine</span>
            <div class="voucher" id="voucher1">
                <div class="carousel-container">
                    <button id="prevBtn">←</button>
                    <button id="nextBtn">→</button>
                    <div class="carousel-slide">
                        <img src="images/vouchers/firstvoucher/voucher3.jpg" id="lastclone" alt="">
                        <img src="images/vouchers/firstvoucher/voucher1.jpeg">
                        <img src="images/vouchers/firstvoucher/voucher2.jpg">
                        <img src="images/vouchers/firstvoucher/voucher3.jpg">
                        <img src="images/vouchers/firstvoucher/voucher1.jpeg" id="firstclone" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="voucher" id="voucher2">
                <div class="carousel-container">
                    <button id="prevBtn">←</button>
                    <button id="nextBtn">→</button>
                    <div class="carousel-slide">
                        <img src="images/vouchers/firstvoucher/voucher3.jpg" id="lastclone" alt="">
                        <img src="images/vouchers/firstvoucher/voucher1.jpeg">
                        <img src="images/vouchers/firstvoucher/voucher2.jpg">
                        <img src="images/vouchers/firstvoucher/voucher3.jpg">
                        <img src="images/vouchers/firstvoucher/voucher1.jpeg" id="firstclone" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this is my JavaScript

```
carousel('#voucher1');
carousel('#voucher2');

function carousel(id){
    const carouselSlide = document.querySelector(id + '.carousel-slide');
    const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll(id + '.carousel-slide img')
    
    const prevBtn = document.querySelector(id + '#prevBtn');
    const nextBtn = document.querySelector(id + '#nextBtn');
    
    let counter = 1;
    let size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)'
    
    nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        let size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;
        if(counter<0) return;
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
        counter++;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
    
        nextBtn.disabled=true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            nextBtn.disabled=false;
        },400)
    });
    
    prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        let size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
        counter--;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
    
        prevBtn.disabled=true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            prevBtn.disabled=false;
        },400)
    });
    
    carouselSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', () =>{
        let size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;
        if(carouselImages[counter].id === 'lastclone'){
            carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
            counter = carouselImages.length-2;
            carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
        }
        if(carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstclone'){
            carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
            counter = carouselImages.length - counter;
            carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
        }
    });
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
        let size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
    }, true);
}
```

I'm one again sorry... Maybe this is a simple problem to fix, but I cannot get a solution for it... Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try like this
`var targetDiv = document.getElementById("voucher1").getElementsByClassName("carousel-slide")[0];
`

Comment: Hello, @jonu29 ! It says ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientWidth')``` at ```let size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;``` I think it doesn't target any of my divs, or are multiple instances of carouselImages and it cannot decide which one to use...

Comment: Also, you cannot use `id + '#prevBtn'` first of because it will give you this strange output: i.e: `#someId#prevButton` which is invalid, secondly, you should not be using IDs at all. Stick to classes. **IDs should be Unique**. Also for `id="lastclone"` etc etc

Comment: Another issue with your code is that you trantition by `px` instead of `%` which (if you do so) remove many unnecessary lines of code like i.e: calculating new changed widths, the window resize function etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some problems:

```
// XXX 
// Unused, undeclared identifier:
carouselA = carousel('#voucher1')


function carousel(id){
// XXX 
// ID selector begins with octothorpe, #.
// XXX
// No element exists with id="voucher1" and class="carousel-slide". 
// You need a space between the two to select the descendant.
document.querySelector(id + '.carousel-slide');
}
```

Instead:

```
document.querySelector(id + ' .carousel-slide');
```

Name variables what they are. For any function param named `id`, pass just the element id and change the callee to reflect that. Else, if you want to pass in the prefixed octothorpe, rename the param `idSelector`.

Answer (score -1):

In your javascript file you have called your function before initialising it. You should always initialise a function before calling it otherwise you will get an error. Try swapping them around and see if that works:

```
//Initialise the function
function carousel(id){
(Your function here)
}

//Then call the function
carousel('#voucher1');
carousel('#voucher2');
```

Comment: Hello @blenmat94! I swapped them around... Now it says that it ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientWidth')```
At ```let size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;```, I think it doesn't target any of my divs...

Comment: It looks like your querySelectors aren't structured correctly. To the best of my knowledge you can't call an id + class - it will return undefined. 
You don't need the "id +" in your carouselSlide query Selector as you are already selecting the ".carousel-slide" class on those elements. 
For your carouselImages, I would suggest adding a class to all of the img tags and using the querySelector to find that instead. This should remove the "undefined" error